# Remove extra column of icons from Angular UI-Grid TreeView

Tags: angularjs, treeview, angular-ui-grid

I want to remove extra column of icons for expand and collapse and merge it with my main treebase column.
[Plunkr Source](http://plnkr.co/edit/vXITsk?p=preview)

In the following link you can see that on a tree view it creates extra column for expansion and collapse but i want to merge it with my first column (name) and i also want to change the icon. Please help me that how can i achieve that.

```
onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  $scope.gridApi.treeBase.on.rowExpanded($scope, function(row) {
    if( row.entity.$$hashKey === $scope.gridOptions.data[50].$$hashKey && !$scope.nodeLoaded ) {
      $interval(function() {
        $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(51,0,
          {name: 'Dynamic 1', gender: 'female', age: 53, company: 'Griddable grids', balance: 38000, $$treeLevel: 1},
          {name: 'Dynamic 2', gender: 'male', age: 18, company: 'Griddable grids', balance: 29000, $$treeLevel: 1}
        );
        $scope.nodeLoaded = true;
      }, 2000, 1);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rowHeader can be hidden just by a property,

```
showTreeRowHeader: false,
```

To have the tree expand buttons as part of the first column, you just need to replicate the template as part of the cell. Define the cell template like this,

```
 { name: 'name', width: '30%' , cellTemplate : "<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" title=\"TOOLTIP\"><div style=\"float:left;\" class=\"ui-grid-tree-base-row-header-buttons\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-tree-base-header': row.treeLevel > -1 }\" ng-click=\"grid.appScope.toggleRow(row,evt)\"><i ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-icon-minus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'expanded', 'ui-grid-icon-plus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'collapsed'}\" ng-style=\"{'padding-left': grid.options.treeIndent * row.treeLevel + 'px'}\"></i> &nbsp;</div>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>" },
```

This plnkr shows a working model, http://plnkr.co/edit/rkHZs0?p=preview

Now to change the icons, all you need to do is to change the

```
<i ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-icon-minus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'expanded', 'ui-grid-icon-plus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'collapsed'}\" ng-style=\"{'padding-left': grid.options.treeIndent * row.treeLevel + 'px'}\"></i>
```

in the cell template. The default template uses ui-grid-icon-plus-squared and ui-grid-icon-minus-squared and can be changed to whatever you like.

Comment: Can you make a plnkr and share

Comment: No thanks i made a mistake now it is completely working :)
let me remove my previous comment too

Comment: As showTreeRowHeader: false works for me but now  I have a large set of data so the first column showing up until the data not loaded please check the following link : http://tidal41.tidalhosting.com/qc/auditor-new/index1.html

Answer (score 0):

The Previous answer of adding following cell template in the column defenition worked for me,

```
cellTemplate: "<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" title=\"TOOLTIP\"><div style=\"float:left;\" class=\"ui-grid-tree-base-row-header-buttons\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-tree-base-header': row.treeLevel > -1 }\" ng-click=\"grid.appScope.toggleRow(row,evt)\"><i ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-icon-minus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'expanded', 'ui-grid-icon-plus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'collapsed'}\" ng-style=\"{'padding-left': grid.options.treeIndent * row.treeLevel + 'px'}\"></i> &nbsp;</div>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>"
```

But remember adding **uiGridTreeBaseService** to the app  controller and then add following method to your controller,

```
$scope.toggleRow = function(row, evt) {
    uiGridTreeBaseService.toggleRowTreeState($scope.gridApi.grid, row, evt);
};
```

If you miss the last two steps then tree won't expand on click of plus sign.

After this, I faced some difficulty with the rows which don't have any children. Their indentation was not proper. So following is the cell template I finally used,

```
 cellTemplate: "<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" title=\"TOOLTIP\"><div style=\"float:left;\" class=\"ui-grid-tree-base-row-header-buttons\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-tree-base-header': row.treeLevel > -1 }\" ng-click=\"grid.appScope.toggleRow(row,evt)\"><i ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-icon-down-dir': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'expanded', 'ui-grid-icon-right-dir': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'collapsed', 'ui-grid-icon-blank': ( ( !grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) && !( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) )}\" ng-style=\"{'padding-left': grid.options.treeIndent * row.treeLevel + 'px'}\"></i> &nbsp;</div>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>"
```

This keeps all the elememnts of same level with the same indent. Don't forget to set **showTreeExpandNoChildren: false** (if you are loading table data at one shot).