# How to align the sibling values under the child values as per child to parent?

Tags: html, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.treeView' ]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'uiGridTreeViewConstants','uiGridTreeBaseService',function ($scope, $http, $interval, uiGridTreeViewConstants,uiGridTreeBaseService ) {
 
  
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: false,
    enableFiltering: false,
    showTreeExpandNoChildren: true,
    showTreeRowHeader: false,
 enableColumnMenus : false,
 rowHeight: 50,
 enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
    enableVerticalScrollbar: 0,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name', width: '30%' , cellTemplate : "<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" title=\"TOOLTIP\"><div style=\"float:left;\" class=\"ui-grid-tree-base-row-header-buttons\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-tree-base-header': row.treeLevel > -1 }\" ng-click=\"grid.appScope.toggleRow(row,evt)\"><i ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-icon-minus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'expanded', 'ui-grid-icon-plus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'collapsed'}\" ng-style=\"{'padding-left': grid.options.treeIndent * row.treeLevel + 'px'}\"></i>&nbsp;</div>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>" },
      { name: 'gender', width: '20%' },
      { name: 'age', width: '20%' },
      { name: 'company', width: '25%' },
      { name: 'state', width: '35%' },
      { name: 'balance', width: '25%', cellFilter: 'currency' }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.treeBase.on.rowExpanded($scope, function(row) {
        if( row.entity.$$hashKey === $scope.gridOptions.data[50].$$hashKey && !$scope.nodeLoaded ) {
          $interval(function() {
            $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(51,0,
              {name: 'Dynamic 1', gender: 'female', age: 53, company: 'Griddable grids', balance: 38000, $$treeLevel: 1},
              {name: 'Dynamic 2', gender: 'male', age: 18, company: 'Griddable grids', balance: 29000, $$treeLevel: 1}
            );
            $scope.nodeLoaded = true;
          }, 2000, 1);
        }
      });
    }
  };

 $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
 .success(function(data) {
   for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
     data[i].state = data[i].address.state;
     data[i].balance = Number( data[i].balance.slice(1).replace(/,/,'') );
   }
   data[0].$$treeLevel = 0;
   data[1].$$treeLevel = 1;
   data[10].$$treeLevel = 1;
   data[11].$$treeLevel = 1;
   data[20].$$treeLevel = 0;
   data[25].$$treeLevel = 1;
   data[50].$$treeLevel = 0;
   data[51].$$treeLevel = 0;
   $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
 });

  $scope.expandAll = function(){
    $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
  };
  
  $scope.collapseAll = function(){
    $scope.gridApi.treeBase.collapseAllRows();
  };
  
  $scope.toggleRow = function( row,evt ){
    uiGridTreeBaseService.toggleRowTreeState($scope.gridApi.grid, row, evt);
    //$scope.gridApi.treeBase.toggleRowTreeState($scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache[rowNum]);
  };

  $scope.toggleExpandNoChildren = function(){
    $scope.gridOptions.showTreeExpandNoChildren = !$scope.gridOptions.showTreeExpandNoChildren;
    $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
  };
}]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button id="expandAll" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="expandAll()">Expand All</button>
  <button id="collapseAll" type="button" class="btn btn-collapse" ng-click="collapseAll()">collapseAll</button>
  <button id="toggleFirstRow" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleRow(0)">Toggle First Row</button>
  <button id="toggleSecondRow" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleRow(1)">Toggle Second Row</button>
  <button id="toggleExpandNoChildren" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleExpandNoChildren()">Toggle Expand No Children</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-tree-view class="grid"></div>
</div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Remove extra column of icons from Angular UI-Grid TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379867/remove-extra-column-of-icons-from-angular-ui-grid-treeview)

As per provided solution above URL it is working fine but in the grid table how to align the sibling values under the child values as per child to parent?

[image]

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.treeView']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'uiGridTreeViewConstants', 'uiGridTreeBaseService',
  function($scope, $http, $interval, uiGridTreeViewConstants, uiGridTreeBaseService) {


    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableSorting: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      showTreeExpandNoChildren: true,
      showTreeRowHeader: false,
      columnDefs: [{
        name: 'name',
        width: '30%',
        cellTemplate: "<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" title=\"TOOLTIP\"><div style=\"float:left;\" class=\"ui-grid-tree-base-row-header-buttons\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-tree-base-header': row.treeLevel > -1 }\" ng-click=\"grid.appScope.toggleRow(row,evt)\"><i ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-icon-minus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'expanded', 'ui-grid-icon-plus-squared': ( ( grid.options.showTreeExpandNoChildren && row.treeLevel > -1 ) || ( row.treeNode.children && row.treeNode.children.length > 0 ) ) && row.treeNode.state === 'collapsed'}\" ng-style=\"{'padding-left': grid.options.treeIndent * row.treeLevel + 'px'}\"></i> &nbsp;</div>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>"
      }, {
        name: 'gender',
        width: '20%'
      }, {
        name: 'age',
        width: '20%'
      }, {
        name: 'company',
        width: '25%'
      }, {
        name: 'state',
        width: '35%'
      }, {
        name: 'balance',
        width: '25%',
        cellFilter: 'currency'
      }],
      onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        $scope.gridApi.treeBase.on.rowExpanded($scope, function(row) {
          if (row.entity.$$hashKey === $scope.gridOptions.data[50].$$hashKey && !$scope.nodeLoaded) {
            $interval(function() {
              $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(51, 0, {
                name: 'Dynamic 1',
                gender: 'female',
                age: 53,
                company: 'Griddable grids',
                balance: 38000,
                $$treeLevel: 1
              }, {
                name: 'Dynamic 2',
                gender: 'male',
                age: 18,
                company: 'Griddable grids',
                balance: 29000,
                $$treeLevel: 1
              });
              $scope.nodeLoaded = true;
            }, 2000, 1);
          }
        });
      }
    };

    $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          data[i].state = data[i].address.state;
          data[i].balance = Number(data[i].balance.slice(1).replace(/,/, ''));
        }
        data[0].$$treeLevel = 0;
        data[1].$$treeLevel = 1;
        data[10].$$treeLevel = 1;
        data[11].$$treeLevel = 1;
        data[20].$$treeLevel = 0;
        data[25].$$treeLevel = 1;
        data[50].$$treeLevel = 0;
        data[51].$$treeLevel = 0;
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      });

    $scope.expandAll = function() {
      $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
    };

    $scope.toggleRow = function(row, evt) {
      uiGridTreeBaseService.toggleRowTreeState($scope.gridApi.grid, row, evt);
      //$scope.gridApi.treeBase.toggleRowTreeState($scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache[rowNum]);
    };

    $scope.toggleExpandNoChildren = function() {
      $scope.gridOptions.showTreeExpandNoChildren = !$scope.gridOptions.showTreeExpandNoChildren;
      $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button id="expandAll" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="expandAll()">Expand All</button>
    <button id="toggleFirstRow" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleRow(0)">Toggle First Row</button>
    <button id="toggleSecondRow" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleRow(1)">Toggle Second Row</button>
    <button id="toggleExpandNoChildren" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleExpandNoChildren()">Toggle Expand No Children</button>
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-tree-view class="grid"></div>
  </div>


  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rkHZs0?p=info)

Comment: Sorry but mentioning the name in the question will not ping the user in another thread.

Comment: hi manoj,i am not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hmmm. You used "Kathir" in the question who answered the other question. He will not be notified. But you can extend the question from there and edit it here. Please add the code that you are using so that people can help you better and faster.

Comment: thanks manoj, i have used same code provided source code from as provided "http://plnkr.co/edit/rkHZs0?p=preview".please let us know if you need further infomration. regards,

Comment: please find the above source code above..please help on this.  regards,Sunny

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
ng-style="{'padding-left': grid.options.treeIndent * row.treeLevel + 'px'}
```

to :

```
ng-style="{'padding-left': (grid.options.treeIndent+10) * row.treeLevel + 'px'}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTuZT.jpg)