# AngularJS ui-grid change header template for expandableRows column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'd like to change the header of expandableRow Column in ui-grid, but I can't seem to figure out how.

[image]

To be clear by the header I mean the circled plus in the image above.
I'm hoping to use this header cell to put a different button there with an entire different functionality than what it currently does.

I attempted to add my own columnDef with `field: "expandableRow"` and a `headerCellTemplate` but I got an error that I can't have duplicated fields (and it broke my grid). 
I can't seem to find info on this in the docs, but maybe I missed it. Anyone know how I can add a template file to replace what's displayed in the cell above?

EDIT: To clarify, I don't want to remove the column entirely like in the the other question suggested as a duplicate. I want to keep the column and the functionality of expanding the rows. I only want to change the expand all button which I've circled in the image above

Comment: it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379867/remove-extra-column-of-icons-from-angular-ui-grid-treeview

Comment: above given existing question should help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove extra column of icons from Angular UI-Grid TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379867/remove-extra-column-of-icons-from-angular-ui-grid-treeview)

Comment: The linked question is about removing the expandRow column entirely and adding the functionality elsewhere, which is not what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @DeejC if the answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QOqIxoArHgBCyP3iDVfa?p=preview

I use $timeout to hide the expand all button:

```
$timeout(function(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-header-cell')[0];
                if (x != null) {
                  var y = x.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-icon-plus-squared')[0];
                  if (y != null) {
                      x.style.backgroundColor = "white"; // "#009933";
                      y.style.visibility = "hidden";
                  }
                }
  });
```

Another option is to change the default expandableTopRowHeader as you can see in the following plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4ChfeZ4cjc8RC9ARdTde?p=preview

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/expandableTopRowHeader',
    '<div class="ui-grid-row-header-cell ui-grid-expandable-buttons-cell" ng-if="grid.options.showExpandAllInHeader"><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><i ng-class="{ "ui-grid-icon-plus-squared" : !grid.expandable.expandedAll, "ui-grid-icon-minus-squared" : grid.expandable.expandedAll }" ng-click="grid.api.expandable.toggleAllRows()">'
);
```

And add to the gridOptions the following option: `showExpandAllInHeader : false`

If you want to change the functionality of the button change the ng-click for the button as you can see in the following plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zzYI9Sn1qJNxgub6dpxQ?p=preview

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/expandableTopRowHeader',
    '<div class="ui-grid-row-header-cell ui-grid-expandable-buttons-cell" ><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><i class="icon-cog" ng-click="grid.appScope.main.test()">'
); 

vm.test = function(){
    alert('Hey!');
  }
```

Comment: This works. Not exactly what I was looking for and I've decided to just put the button elsewhere. But thanks for the answer